# Replace suPHP on RHEL

Tags: linux, apache, suphp

I offer a web-service to the about 50k users of our university. Each user has it's directory-structure with web-pages, CGI-scripts or PHP-pages/programs. Apache uses suexec and suphp to run the scripts of the corresponding user with the uid of the user and not with the uid of the web-server. The service is very popular, people use and appreciate the service.

From the 50k users, about 10-15 are active at any time. Apache spawns processes for them, suphp changes the uid, the request get's processed, the process is then terminated. The active users use apache/PHP resources, the inactive users don't bother anybody.

As most of you probably know, the sun set over suPHP quite a few years ago. I am looking for alternatives:

php-fpm: to the best of my understanding, I would have to create 50k processes (one for each user). Some will be used, some not. If this basic understanding is wrong, please correct me and if possible give me an example of how php-fpm can dynamically change uids.

containerization (e.g., kubernetes): the same problem as php-fpm. Resources get wasted on the users that use the service seldomly.

on-demand provisioning: we provision the service on request, as opposed to by-default. Our users, however, don't have the most economic handling on free resources. I'm afraid that they order the service, use it for an experiment or a course and then keep it "just in case".

Any idea on how to replace suPHP in a resource-saving manner is greatly appreciated.